# Installing elementary (replacing ubuntu) without having to reinstall applications

Tags: release-loki, system-installation, applications

Is it possible to move from a single boot ubuntu to single boot elementary and not have to reinstall all my applications? I'm running single boot because my laptop only has a 120 GB SSD.

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and want to switch to loki - but it takes ages to reinstall android studio (and other programs), as my internet isn't the best. So was wondering if there's a faster way.

Comment: You should read: http://blog.elementary.io/post/153360513026/busting-major-myths-around-elementary-os

Comment: @JorgeR.Marín Thanks, interesting read. Not really relevant though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reinstall elementary to ensure that you get a fully functional system.

However, you can keep a list of the packages installed with

```
dpkg --get-selections > package-list-file
```

and backup this file and the packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives` so that the packages not specific to elementary OS 0.4 would not be downloaded again. This will only work if you have not done any `apt-get clean` / `apt-get autoclean` since you have installed the packages.

After the installation of elementary OS 0.4 you can copy every `.deb` file from you backup medium back to `/var/cache/apt/archives`. Do not forget to add each PPA that you have used on the original system to the new one before as well. After these steps you  restore packages with

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < package-list-file
```

There might be some packages that you have to install/fix a little but it should work for most of the software installed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **NO** (as elementary OS is not an update of Ubuntu)

Nevertheless, It's possible to install pantheon (the elementary OS desktop) on top of Ubuntu. You will get a functioning desktop, but you have to remember that it's not the same as a full installation so you may get some small errors.

To  install the elementary desktop do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop`
```